# SVG in azw3 for kindle paperwhite always going to new page

Tags: kindle, calibre, svg

I made svg file in illustrator and I am trying to put it inline in azw3 book with calibre. svg is 680x100. But everything I do put this svg on new page on kindle. Or this picture is deformed.

Is there a way to properly put svg?

Book I trying to make is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B895oXL9F_s6ME9faWhvVnRaR0U/view?usp=sharing

I am trying to make book about presocratic philosopher from https://archive.org/details/presocraticphilo033229mbp more readable on kindle.

Comment: I hope this discussion is still alive? It is important because svg is the future - it scales easily and looks so much better. I am no html wizzard and I just place the svg like this: (img alt="name" height="auto" src=name.svg" width="50%") I guess there must exist a smarter way.....

Comment: I didn't have time to try your solution, but as soon as I do I will write you if did worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is not strictly an answer to your question, but...

I can't read your file but I have had a look at the epub and the pdf from archive.org. It seems to me that it would be a simply immense amount of work to format that book satisfactorily as xhtml for use on an ereader. It looks to me to be a case where the pdf has a definite advantage.

If you are going to do that work (or have already done it). Wouldn't it make sense to make it available to an many other interested people as possible by producing the ebook as epub (an open and documented format) and then converting that to basic mobi. With your illustration as a PNG bitmap.

There's a place for experimenting with exotic ebook and image formats, but I don't think this project is it.

Comment: Here is epub: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B895oXL9F_s6LWZ3djhnd0NEUFE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Here is epub: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B895oXL9F_s6LWZ3djhnd0NEUFE/view?usp=sharing

It is slow work, but I really want to read it from my kindle. Btw first link you can open with calibre. I want to use svg because I expect to look better then png. And it will take less space.Here is one of just few things I want to put as images: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B895oXL9F_s6cmtNbWtOdEFVZmc/view?usp=sharing

All other text is OCR-ed with gImagerReader, so it can be stored as text (even old Greek). I will post book publicly when I finish it, but that will last. All help is welcome.

Comment: That's very impressive. Do you get a satisfactory result when you use Calibre to convert your epub to mobi?

Comment: First it not finished yet. I came to half of first chapter. Second whatever I do that image is going on separate page.

Comment: I have same result with converting epub to mobi, or from azw3 to mobi. Best result on kindle is actually using azw3. But I still have problem with that image.

Comment: OK. But as azw3 is an undocumented Amazon proprietary format and has to be reverse-engineered by the Calibre developers, nobody can say for sure what is expected. I see that azw3 is another name for kf8, some information here:http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/KF8 - I wish I could be more help, but good luck with your project anyway.

Comment: If you take to read it, you can send me anything which I miss to correct from the book. That would be also helpful.